# Angular 2: How do you access component variables within an event (scope issue)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a click event on my component, that needs to access private variables from the component itself. However I seem to be running into a scoping issue: the keyword `this` no longer refers to the component's scope but rather the scope of the event. Help!

```
onclick(event){
  for(var i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) { ... }
}
```

In the above example, `this.arr` is undefined because it does not belong to the event scope.

How do I get access to the component scope from here?

Comment: This requires more context. The problem is not in the code you provided. Normally there is no scope issue as long as you are not using `function () {` or pass function references around like `someFunc(myFuncRef)`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the event handler is set like so: `element.addEventListener("click", this.onclick, false);`

Comment: That's exactly what I meant with "pass function references around like someFunc(myFuncRef)" ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `.bind(this)` to fix `this`

```
element.addEventListener("click", this.onclick.bind(this), false);
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you :)

Comment: This solved my issue with binding dynamic button with a function to handle timeout.